# Remote filtering; no return value

Tags: extjs, filter, grid-layout

Extjs 5.0

In a grid, I have a tollbar with a textfield used to filter the grid (remote).

Works fine.

However, if I do the filtering with a word that does not exist in the database (eg 'mywxtyz'), gives the error: Ext.JSON.decode (): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String, and the output is null.

What I wanted was when the search did not return any record (not exist in the database), a simple message or a text in a grid emptyText, or in a window, was displayed.

how can I do this?

Thanks in  advance.

My code:

```
onButtonFilter : function(button, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
var me = this;
var textfield = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#filter')[0];
var grid =  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#griditemId')[0];
var store = grid.getStore();

if (form.isValid()) {
    store.proxy.extraParams = {
        action : 'filterGrid',
        name : textfield.getValue()
    },
    store.load();
  }
}
```

Example of my PHP:

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$action = $_REQUEST['action'];

switch($action){

   case "create":{
   }

   case "read":{

    $start = $_REQUEST['start'];
    $limit = $_REQUEST['limit'];

    $statement = $conexao->stmt_init();

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT name, email FROM contact LIMIT ?,  ?";
    $sqlTotal = "SELECT COUNT(name) as num FROM contact";


    if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) AND $_REQUEST['action'] == 'filterGrid') {

         $name = $_REQUEST['name'];

         $sqlQuery = "SELECT name, email
                      FROM contact
                      WHERE name like '%$name%'
                      LIMIT ?,  ?";

         $sqlTotal = "SELECT COUNT(name) as num
                      FROM contact
                      WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
    }


    if ($statement = $conexao->prepare($sqlQuery)){
        $statement->bind_param("ii", $start, $limit);
        $statement->execute();


        $statement->bind_result($col1, $col2);

        while($statement->fetch()){
            $output[] = array($col1, $col2);
        };


    if ($statement = $conexao->query($sqlTotal)){
        $row = $statement->fetch_row();
        $total = $row[0];
    }

    $sucess = array("success" => mysqli_errno($conexao) == 0);

    echo json_encode(array(
        "success" => $sucess,
        "total" => $total,
        "data" => $output
    ));

    $conexao->close();

    break;
  }

   case "update":{
  }

   case "destroy":{
  }
 }
?>
```

The store:

```
Ext.define('APP.store.StoreList', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

itemId:'mystore',

model: 'SPP.model.ModelList',

pageSize: 25,
autoLoad:true,
autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 25},

autoSync: false,

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',

    actionMethods:{
            create:'POST',
            read:'POST',
            update:'POST',
            destroy:'POST'
    },


    api: {
        create: 'php/crudActionList.php?action=create',
        read: 'php/crudActionList.php?action=read',
        update: 'php/crudActionList.php?action=update',
        destroy: 'php/crudActionList.php?action=destroy'
    },

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data',
        totalProperty:'total',
        successProperty: 'success'
    },

    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true,
        encode: true,
        rootProperty: 'data'
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the $output and $total variables are empty when no matches are found. Perhaps if you initialize it and set it to an empty array before the while statement, that will do the trick.

So instead of

```
    while($statement->fetch()){
        $output[] = array($col1, $col2);
    };
```

it should be

```
   $output = []; 
   while($statement->fetch()){
        $output[] = array($col1, $col2);
    };
```

Same thing with the total piece. Set $total to 0 ahead of time.

So the following

```
if ($statement = $conexao->query($sqlTotal)){
    $row = $statement->fetch_row();
    $total = $row[0];
}
```

Should be

```
$total = 0;
if ($statement = $conexao->query($sqlTotal)){
    $row = $statement->fetch_row();
    $total = $row[0];
}
```

UPDATE: To provide a message to the user that no records were returned, you'll want to use the callback option of the load function.
 http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load

So, something like the following should work:

```
store.load({
scope: this,
callback: function(records, operation, success) {
    if(records.length === 0){
      Ext.Msg.alert("Nothing Found", "No records found");
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks ekbarber for your help.

Comment: Thanks ekbarber. Your suggestion helped a lot. No error is now displayed. However, I want to inform the user that was not found any record. Any idea how to do this? Thanks again.